# Maxima gives crazy answer for integrate(exp(x^2))

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to learn how to use Maxima. Something goes wrong with integrate :

```
(%i) integrate(exp(x^3),x,1,2);
(%o) (gamma_incomplete(1/3,-8)-gamma_incomplete(1/3,-1))/3
(%i) float(%);
(%o) .3333333333333333 (- 715.7985328824436 %i - 413.26647564521807)
(%i) expand(%);
(%o) - 238.59951096081454 %i - 137.75549188173935
```

What do you think?

Comment: This integral should be real (and positive).

Answer (score 1):

Comparing Maxima's result to Wolfram Alpha, looks like Maxima has assumed that -x/((-x^3)^(1/3)) = 1. After debugging this for a bit, I can't tell if that term was originally in the result and it got simplified away, or if it was never there. With that term in place, and using the principal branch for the cube root, I get 275.510983 + (epsilon)*%i which agrees with a numerical result, namely quad_qags(exp(x^3), x, 1, 2) => 275.510983.

For the record, this integral is handled as "Type 1a" in maxima/src/sin.lisp, in the function INTEGRATE-EXP-SPECIAL.

Comment: The global flag 'domain' governs the simplification of the cube root. Here's what I get now, which is, I believe, the result OP is looking for: domain:complex; integrate(exp(x^3), x, 1, 2); => ((-1)^(2/3)*gamma_incomplete(1/3,-8)-(-1)^(2/3)*gamma_incomplete(1/3,-1))/3 %, numer, expand; => 275.5109837633115-7.71234927772942E-14*%i (sorry for the messy code; I don't know how to put a blank line into a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with a complex answer to an exponential integration. In general, If you integrate e^(x^n) you're going to run into strange functions like the incomplete gamma function etc, because the answer isn't expressible in conventional functions, so has no conventional real analytic solution.

However, I think that there's definitely some inaccuracy here. Mathematica gives a different answer, much closer to a real answer, and as I ask for more accuracy, the real part appears to tend to zero, as you would expect.

If you want to numerically integrate (and it sounds like you do), you'll could use a different function. `integrate` is for analytical integration, which is why it gave you a formula rather than a number. Look up `quad_qags` and its friends for some really clever numerical integration functions.

Comment: @user29831 Perhaps "some inaccuracy" is understating it and "a bug" might be nearer the mark. Maybe it's worth raising this issue via [the mailing list](http://www.math.utexas.edu/mailman/listinfo/maxima).